# MySQL number math precision

Tags: mysql, math

I have a simple problem to understand:

```
SELECT (200/0.713788), 280.1952*0.713788, 280.195240043*0.713788
```

Results:

1. col: 280.1952, why is it truncated? What is the rule for the number of decimals?
2. col: 199.9999714176, this is good, it can't be precise because I copied the first col's result in here.
3. col: 199.999999999812884, this is what I interests me the most. Why it's not 200 exactly?

Comment: Additionally to scaisEdge answer, this might answer your "why?" : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-float.html

Answer (score 1):

Your 280.195240043*0.713788   is = 199.999999999812884

if you need  a rounded  number you should use Round()

```
SELECT (200/0.713788), 280.1952*0.713788, round(280.195240043*0.713788 , 8)
```